# Linux dma device driver dma_request_channel fails

Tags: c, linux-kernel, embedded, driver, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to write a platform driver that interfaces with the DMA on an embedded system. We are using the Zedboard and Xilinx's AXI DMA IP. However, I believe our errors are related to the Linux kernel.

To get a `tx/rx` channel for the DMA, linux provides the `dma_request_channel` function. This function uses a filter and a filter parameter that needs to match the DMA. This function gets a list of all the DMA's available in the system and uses the filter to match it to the one we want. However, it would seem that this is not able to get all the available DMA's but only one. ARM cores come with their own PL330 hard `IP DMA`. That is the only one it sees.

The kernel code is oh so convoluted to understand that I am stuck in the list header file [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/list.h?a=sh#L350)

Could someone explain what `LIST_HEAD_INIT` does? What `C` syntax is that?

Do I need to to something do have the hardware peripheral become visible to the OS? I thought the device tree takes care of that and we have included it in the device tree. We can also get the base address of this by using the get_platform_resources API.

Comment: How did you tell the Linux DMA subsystem about the DMA controller?

Comment: Um.... that is kind of my question?

Comment: What kernel are you using? What have you added to the device tree? Which driver is supposed to handle that part of the DT?

Comment: I'm using 3.9 from Xilinx's github repo. The device tree is made by Xilinx's device tree generator from their ISE Design Suite's SDK. That being said, it does contain a node for the AXI DMA. The driver is also provided by Xilinx but we are not sure how to use it. The driver comes with a test and the test itself is not able to find any channels. So my question was is there something we need to do in order to have the OS recognize all available DMAs or is adding a node to the device tree enough?

Comment: I do not see the Xilinx DMA driver in the standard kernel. If you have a problem with Xilinx's modifications, you have to ask *them*.

Comment: Like I said, it is the kernel from Xilinx's github repo. And I am not sure if it is a problem with their stuff. The device tree is a linux thing. The driver is a linux thing. The only Xilinx IP is the DMA itself which works because other peripherals that use it work. Finally, I have no "problem" with anything. I am simply asking this question to understand how device drivers work. If I request a dma channel, why does it look for only one DMA? The list should be populated by the device tree. Well, the device tree has the correct list. I don't see Xilinx coming in here. I hve asked them as well.

Comment: Looking at the [source code of the xilinx_axidma driver](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/tree/master/drivers/dma/xilinx), there appears to be exactly one DMA channel per platform device.

Comment: Exactly my point. If there is a channel, why isn't it found?

Anyways, the problem was that the device tree required child nodes for the s2mm and mm2s channels. [Here](http://www.zedboard.org/content/axi-dma-driver-linux) is the solution and how to proceed forward, for anyone that references this later.

Answer (score 0):

`Could someone explain what LIST_HEAD_INIT does? What C syntax is that?`

`LIST_HEAD_INIT` is a macro which initializes the members of `struct list_head` in `LIST_HEAD` macro.

```
#define LIST_HEAD_INIT(name) { &(name), &(name) }

#define LIST_HEAD(name) \
          struct list_head name = LIST_HEAD_INIT(name) 

//Taken from scripts/kconfig/list.h    
struct list_head {
          struct list_head *next, *prev;
  };
```

Here both prev and next is initialized with same member.